# what do the different GitHub code colors mean?

Tags: syntax-highlighting

Is someone able to tell me what the different GitHub code colors mean? In the image below I have mix of red, orange, white and blue. Some of them I can probably guess at but I haven't been able to find transparent information on this, or at least I'm not searching the correct terms.

[image: Code colrs]

Comment: This is syntax highlighting for the language python. This is not a github thing.

Comment: Also that highlight is specific for IDE

Comment: Capitalized terms are properly treated as types, while lowercase names are just variables. Keywords are red, comments light-blue and numbers (and likely strings) blue.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz thank you! I was concerned about why some variables were orange and others were white, but it seems to be due to capitalization(?)

Comment: I've rolled back your edit since it changes the question which the answer below accurately answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a feature called [syntax highlighting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntax_highlighting). It helps developers to code because every color has its "meaning". Most code editors and services which display code have this feature, it's not a Github-only thing.

### Themes

Often you have the choice of different themes, in which the code gets presented. These are just color palettes in which color has a meaning. Most developers have some favorite themes, especially light or dark themes.

But different themes also have different colors for keywords, types and variables. So you can identify the code parts faster, than just black text on white background.

### Explanation of colors:

- red: keywords
- blue: strings, numbers, operators
- white: variables
- gray: comments
- orange: classes

Comment: Thank you, I at least have a better idea of what to search now

Comment: @GeoMonkey If you want to change the appearance of GitHub, you can visit this page: https://github.com/settings/appearance
Also, you can search in the Google Chrome Webstore for themes and more. I hope you will find something you like